# Pandas Data Frame length is not matching

Tags: python, pandas

I don't understand why my `not in may` result is different. Which one of this approach is correct?

```
len(filter_S)
in_may_filter_s = filter_S[(filter_S.REQUESTED_DATE >= '2017-05-1') & (filter_S.REQUESTED_DATE < '2017-06-1')]
not_in_may_filter_s = filter_S[~(filter_S.REQUESTED_DATE >= '2017-05-1') & (filter_S.REQUESTED_DATE < '2017-06-1')]

print("Number of Result Status  'S' in May {}".format(len(in_may_filter_s)))
print("Number of Result Status  'S' not in May {}".format(len(filter_S) - len(in_may_filter_s)))
print("Number of Result Status  'S' not in May {}".format(len(not_in_may_filter_s)))
```

Output:
Number of Result Status (OBR:25) 'S' in May 1436
Number of Result Status (OBR:25) 'S' not in May 467
Number of Result Status 'S' not in May 464

Comment: You seem to be missing a `~` for the second comparison in the `not_in_may_filter_s` assignment.

Comment: Though it's probably easier to use something like (pseudo-code) `date < 2017-05-1 | date > 2017-05-31`.

Comment: @Evert you were right I was missing other '~` Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probabily it's your `NOT`. Add `~` to the other filter too. Like:

```
not_in_may_filter_s = filter_S[~((filter_S.REQUESTED_DATE >= '2017-05-1') & (filter_S.REQUESTED_DATE < '2017-06-1'))]
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I didn't wrap both filter with `()`